# How can I get my service dependencies to be parsed without restarting the server?

Tags: windows-server-2003, service, configuration, dependencies

We had a service set up with HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\servicename\DependOnService of other services set to this one service.  When I would shut down the one service, all its dependents would shut down automatically.

However, after some internal changes to these in-house services, they no longer depend on the one service.  So, I removed it from their DependOnService keys using regedit.  The problem is, in the Services window, it still insists that if I shut down the one service the others will be shut down, but I don't want to cause any more down time on them than I have already today.  I've tried closing the Services window and launching it again, to no avail.  Is there any way to get it to re-read the DependOnService data?

Comment: good question, but I'm pretty sure you'll need to reboot the server.

Comment: Agree with @tonyroth. You've made a change to a very fundamental component of the OS. Time to reboot.

Comment: Oddly, one of them picked up by itself for no apparent reason, but the other three were still on the list when I would try to shut it down.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't.  You have to reboot.

Answer (score 1):

From an elevated command prompt, enter (Surround service name in quotes if it has a space):

```
sc config <service name> depend= /
```

Comment: thanks, it worked for me.